# Can/Should I run svnadmin pack on a mirrored repository

Tags: svn, mirror, pack, svnadmin, svnsync

We're mirroring a 1.6 repo using svnsync. We run svnadmin pack once a week on the master repo, but I'm wondering if we can or should also run it on the mirrored repository. From what I understand of SVN internals, the filesystem changes svnadmin pack makes would not be mirrored (which makes sense I guess).
Can someone confirm if I can/should run svnadmin pack on a mirror?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it turns out it was ok to run on the mirrored repo.